# How to always show decimals of float?

Tags: c#, .net

I've built console progress bar, it works just fine, but the problem is that on numbers with no decimals it does not print it. I need it to print `100,0` instead of `100`. Probably easy task, but I don't know how.

```
float percent = (float)(progress * 100) / total;
Console.Write(" [{0}] [{1}]", userID, Math.Round(percent, 1));
```

Comment: You can find the standard formatters on the MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx It also has a format utility you can download to play with results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `" [{0}] [{1:0.0}]"` instead:

```
Console.Write(" [{0}] [{1:0.0}]", userID, Math.Round(percent, 1));
```

Comment: Thanks, this works even faster, probably because I'm not rounding it with Math.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will do "Bankers Rounding".  If you want to round away from zero, specify the `MidpointRoundingMode`.

Comment: In that scenario, the rounding expression would be `Math.Round(percent, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`. Good to know, though, since 2.5 => 2 and 3.5 => 4 is not what most people expect.

Answer (score 1):

[**Fixed-Point**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#FFormatString)

```
Console.Write(" [{0}] [{1:F1}]", userID, Math.Round(percent, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write(" [{0}] [{1}]", userID, Math.Round(percent, 1).ToString("N1"));
```